# How to use select with update query ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count points for each business for having deals or gallery :

so if the business has un empty deal, or has at least one gallery , business_data_count should be 2.

this what i've tried :

```
UPDATE `business`  businessTable SET 
            business_data_count 
            =
            sum(
                            (
                            SELECT  
                                    CASE  
                                         WHEN count(*)>= 1 then count(*)
                                         ELSE 0
                                     END as points
                            FROM gallery WHERE bussId=businessTable.bussId
                            )

                            +

                            (
                            SELECT
                                  case 
                                      WHEN deal!='' then 1
                                      ELSE 0
                                  end
                            FROM business WHERE  bussId=businessTable.bussId 
                            )
             where 1
```

but i got this error :
you cant specify table business for update

How to fix this ?

Comment: This query is very hard to read, please see if you can format it better. The main reason for the error is that you can't select from the table you are updating, so if you can format your query and explain your goals it may be easier to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do a separate select from the update table. Try this instead (untested):

```
UPDATE business
   SET business_data_count = (deal != '')
       + (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM gallery
           WHERE bussId = business.bussId);
```

On a separate note, it's generally bad practice to store data that can be easily extracted with a query, such as the above.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't understand your note, could you explain more.

Comment: @david I mean that a column like `business_data_count` doesn't actually add data to your table; it's merely a function of preexisting data. When you have a value that be computed from existing data, it's generally better to use a query to do the computation as necessary than to store redundant information in your database.

Comment: now i understand, actually i stored this value because i will use it in real time. so it will be faster. i will update this col once a day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo.
I think you should have:

```
UPDATE `business`.businessTable SET
```

instead of

```
UPDATE `business`  businessTable SET
```

If you use the schema when defining your table in your query, you need to separate them with a dot (.).

Maybe it is not the only problem, but that's the first that comes to mind.

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually i was trying to use aliasing.